# Rewrite specific file - Wordpress making it difficult

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Right so basically I'm trying to rewrite with my .htaccess file so that http://example.com/filename.php is viewable via. http://example.com/filename this works fine as long as I have it like this:
examplesite/folder/filename.php is accessible via. examplesite/folder/filename

However I'm trying to achieve this to work but in the root, rather than inside a directory.

I'm pretty sure the reason why it doesn't work is due to the fact of having a .htaccess setup for Wordpress rewrite structure in the root of my site.

I have this in my working directory .htaccess (/ternet-address/):

> RewriteRule ^ternet-address$ grabip.php [L]

but when I add it to the .htaccess in root and move my file grabip.php into root as well, I just get thrown a 404 error.

Any ideas? Been bugging my mind for weeks trying to solve this for different situations!

Comment: Is your wordpress installed under `examplesite/folder`, or is it installed under `examplesite`

Comment: Wordpress is installed under examplesite